# How to check MGMTCLAS?

Tags: storage, mainframe, administration

I am aware that MGMTCLAS names are defined by storage administration. Can someone tell me,  is there any way we can find out what all MGMTCLAS we have in our system?

Comment: if you have access to ISMF, you can use this: go to option 5 then option 1 to generate a list

Comment: Also keep in mind that you may only be allowed to use some of those management classes.

Comment: Ask the storage people? Why do you want to know?